# Why ssrs 2005 report takes long time for execution when using parameter?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

I am trying to execute one SSRS 2005 report. This report takes one parameter.
If I don't use the parameter and write the value directly then it runs in 10 sec. eg.

```
Select * from table1 where id = 122
```

If I use parameter then it takes long time like 10 to 15 min like

```
Select * from table1 where id = @id
```

I don't know why this thing is happening.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: r u executing the query using a SP ?

Comment: NO, I am not using SP. I have just added one parameter in the ssrs 2005 report and then i m using that parameter in the query in report.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to answer the question as asked: only *you* have the info to determine why things aren't performing well.

What we can do however, is answer the question "How to investigate SSRS performance issues?". One of the best tools I've found so far is to use the [ExecutionLog2 View](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/robertbruckner/archive/2009/01/05/executionlog2-view.aspx) in the ReportServer catalog database. In your case the important columns to look at:

- TimeDataRetrieval, for time spent connecting to the data source and retrieving data rows
- TimeProcessing, for time spent turning the data rows into the report
- TimeRendering, for time spent creating the final output (pdf, html, excel, etc)

This will give you a starting point for investigating further. Most likely (from your description) I'd guess the problem lies in the first bit. A suitable follow up step would be to analyze the query that is executed by SSRS, possibly using the execution plan.

Comment: According to your first point, why this point is not applicable when I use value direct in the query where clause like "id=120" by using value direct in the query make its execution very fast. but when I use send this value to the query using Parameter then its very slow. I think may be problem is in the parameter otherwise the query should slow in other case as well when i was providing value directly in the query.

Comment: I want to addon more thing... my query is pretty big and it contain 7 big subqueries as well. If i remove these subqueries then passing value by parameter or direct value dont effect the query performance.

Comment: That would probably mean the problem *is* in your query. Have you tried running it through the query analyzer / execution plan? And have you followed my suggestion yet and checked the results of the ExecutionLog2? Let us know how you finally solved your question (note that you can answer your own question, should my answer not suffice).

Answer (score 0):

1) try replacing your sub queries with join logic. To the best possible. I know many a times sub-queries feel more logical as it makes the problem flow thru when we are thinking in macro view [this result set] gets [that result sets out put].
2) Can also put index as well. And since its int it will be faster.